# Output categories in tagger?

Tags: tags, devdemon

I'm using DevDemon Tagger to output a list of categories. Everything is working fine but I am acing trouble getting categories to out put. Other items output no problem.

My code is below:

{exp:tagger:entries tag="{get:tag}" custom_fields="categories|dl_authors"}

{tagger:entry_title}
{tagger:categories}{tagger:category_url_title} {/tagger:categories}

{/exp:tagger:entries}

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Discovered I can use exp:tagger:entries_quick with a standard exp:channel:entries inside it and then access items like normal, but this seems inefficient especially if the tag has many items?

{exp:tagger:entries_quick tag="{get:tag}"}
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{tagger:entry_ids}"  channel="the channel" status="open" show_future_entries="no" show_expired="no"}
// Normal stuff in here {title} {tagger:categories}{tagger:category_url_title} {/tagger:categories}

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:tagger:entries_quick}